# Why do Pride flags fly over British police stations, prisons and other government buildings?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, prison, flag

Insofar as this question may have a legal answer, by what provisions or instruments are they flown or allowed to be flown? Who would have the power to decide what flags are flown over such institutions? For example, the Daniel Quasar “progress pride” flag flies over HMP Pentonville. What provisions might govern such a practise?

Comment: There are police rules concerning flags on police stations, but I can't (yet) find them on open source. I'll post an answer if/when I can.

Comment: Are you only interested in prisons or in other goverment buildings?

Answer (score 5):

Google england law flying flags

First result [Flying flags: a plain English guide - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/flying-flags-a-plain-english-guide/flying-flags-a-plain-english-guide)

> ... Some flags require formal consent (permission) from the local
> planning authority, whereas others like the Union Flag do not. The
> detailed controls over flag flying are set out in detailed regulations
> (see links below). ...
>
> All flag flying is subject to some standard conditions
>
> ...
>
> Subject to compliance with the standard conditions, there are 3
> categories of flag:
>
> (a) flags which can be flown without consent of the local planning
> authority
>
> (b) flags which do not need consent provided they comply with further
> restrictions (referred to as “deemed consent” in the Regulations)
>
> (c) flags which require consent (“express consent”)
>
> ...
>
> (b) Flags which do not require consent provided they comply with
> certain restrictions [include for example] ... the Rainbow flag (6 horizontal equal stripes
> of red, orange, yellow, green, blue and violet).
>
> ...
>
> The regulations governing the flying of flags in England are set out
> in the Town and Country Planning (Control of Advertisements)
> Regulations 2007 (as amended in 2012 and in 2021).
>
> These regulations, including relevant amendments to flying of flags,
> can be viewed on the government legislation website:
>
> - [Town and Country Planning (Control of Advertisements) (England) Regulations 2007](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2007/783/contents/made)
> - [The Town and Country Planning (Control of Advertisements) (England) (Amendment) Regulations 2012](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2012/2372/contents/made)
> - [The Town and Country Planning (Control of Advertisements) (England) (Amendment) Regulations 2021](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2021/617/contents/made) ...

Comment: Decent answer but I feel it could still address whose decision it would be to fly them. I mean even if they do not require such higher consent as referred to in the regulations surely the decision and initiative to fly them on behalf of such a public body as the police or prison service would lie with some office or other.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Is there a reason you believe the decision wasn't made by the governor of the prison?

Comment: I don’t think that it was or wasn’t but the massive coordination suggests that it is a more central power.

Comment: I don't think there's a law that says "now fly this flag on prisons." There *might* be a policy.

Comment: @Lag Would be easy enough to disprove. Just find a prison that isn't flying one.

Comment: @Seekinganswers it's the same reason everyone was flying Ukraine flags after 2022-02-22 - they wanted 2